# Change XML attribute in Datasource via ComboBox TwoWay Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, data-binding, .net-4.5

This is my XAML sample code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="DataProvider" Source="datacontext.xml" XPath="/"  />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ComboBox Name="combobox1" Width="100" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Contact/ContactMethods//*}">
        <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
            <Binding XPath="Contact\ContactMethods/*[@Selected='True']" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
        </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

This is my XML data source:

```
<Contact ShowsInterest="true">
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
  <ContactMethods>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Phone</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Email</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="True">Letter</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Mobile</ContactMethod>
  </ContactMethods>
</Contact>
```

The code above displays the contacts methods as the combobox. The ContactMethod which has the XML Selected Attribute set to true is preselected in the combobox and displayed at startup.

It looks like this:

[image: This is how it looks like]

I use the following method to save the data:

```
private void OnSubmitClick(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    DataProvider.Document.Save("datacontext.xml");
}
```

This method changes the value of the ContactMethod and not the Selected Attribute.

If you select `Mobile` and click [submit] the result looks like this:

```
  <ContactMethods>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Phone</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Email</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="True">Mobile</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Mobile</ContactMethod>
  </ContactMethods>
```

The change is persisted where the `Selected` Attribute equals true. The value which the control was bound to is overwritten.

**Desired Result:** it should look like this:

```
  <ContactMethods>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Phone</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Email</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="False">Letter</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Selected="True">Mobile</ContactMethod>
  </ContactMethods>
```

**Question:**
How do i change the Selected Attribute of the currently selected item? Is it possible to persist the changes made with the desired xml data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this: instead of having multiple Selected attributes just create a Selected attribute in `ContactMethods` element:

```
<Contact ShowsInterest="true">
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
  <ContactMethods Selected="Phone">
    <ContactMethod>Phone</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod>Email</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod>Letter</ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod>Mobile</ContactMethod>
  </ContactMethods>
</Contact>
```

Then just bind your ComboBox like this:

```
    <ComboBox Name="combobox1" Width="100" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod}"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding XPath=Contact/ContactMethods/@Selected}">
    </ComboBox>
```

**Another option without changing the source XML structure**:
The idea is to alter the XML at the time of persistence setting the selected attribute flag to the `ComboBox` `SelectedValue` :

Change your `OnSubmitClick` method to:

```
    private void OnSubmitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xe = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(DataProvider.Document));
        var elements = xe.Elements("ContactMethods").Elements("ContactMethod").ToList();
        var sel = combobox1.SelectedValue;
        foreach(XElement element in elements)
        {
            element.SetAttributeValue("Selected", (string)sel == element.Value ? "True" : "False");
        }
        xe.Save("datacontext.xml");
        //DataProvider.Document.Save("datacontext.xml");
    }
```

And your `ComboBox` definition to:

```
       <ComboBox Name="combobox1" Width="100" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod}"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding XPath=Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod[@Selected\=\'True\'],Mode=OneTime}">
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that would be easy. Unfortunately i have to use a given data source. I can't influence the data structure.

Comment: Check my other alternative, just modified the answer

Comment: i would prefer a solution with less code behind because the whole XAML/CodeBehind has to generated automatically during runtime. I will wait a few days to see if there are other ways, if not i will mark your post as answer.

Comment: Cool, I'd also be interested in hearing more options. I couldn't think of anything else..

Comment: maybe with a third binding? the first binding for the ItemSource, the second for initializing the value displayed on start up (OneTime or OneWay binding) and the third to change the selected attribute.

Comment: The problem is that you not only need to set the selected attribute, you need to set all the others (not selected) to false.

Comment: okay lets face it: It is not possible to do it without any code behind.